# How can I take document from Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am dealing with the Futurebuilder in the Flutter, and  I want to create a Future function that is going to take data from my Firebase. After that, I want to use that data inside of the text widget, so I tried to write this function to take data from firebase.

```
Future getData() async {
  var fb = Firestore.instance;

  DocumentSnapshot dr =  (await fb.collection("records").document("the record").get());

  return dr.toString();
}
```

But when I tried to use that data inside of the FutureBuilder, I am taking just *Instance of 'DocumentSnapsot'* text.

**Here you can see my FutureBuilder codes**

```
 body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (_ ,snapshot){

            if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return RaisedButton(
                child: Text("loading" ),
                onPressed: null,
              );
            }


            if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done) {
              return RaisedButton(
                child: Text(snapshot.data),
                onPressed: () {},
              );
            }




            return null;
          }
```

**And this is the result, after the running program:**

[image: After the running]

**Also, This my firebase. I just want to reach, and manipulate 0 value inside of the program.**

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing `.toString();`in `getData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DocumentSnapshot` `toString` method does not provide the data contained within the document you are trying to retrieve. To obtain the data in the document from a `DocumentSnapshot`, do `dr.data`, which returns a `Map` containing the fields and the associated data of those fields stored in the document. This should be done in your `getData()` method.

The `toString` method for `DocumentSnapshot` returns `"Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'"`, hence why your button is showing that instead of what you intend.